# Replace "/U+[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}/" with proper unicode character in shell pipeline with sed eval flag

Tags: text-processing, sed, character-encoding, unicode, special-characters

I am trying to properly visualize the existing characters that listed in the `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h` file.

It has lines like:

```c
#define XK_onethird    0x0ab0  /* U+2153 VULGAR FRACTION ONE THIRD */
#define XK_twothirds   0x0ab1  /* U+2154 VULGAR FRACTION TWO THIRDS */
#define XK_onefifth    0x0ab2  /* U+2155 VULGAR FRACTION ONE FIFTH */
```

I would like to display them like:

```c
#define XK_onethird    0x0ab0  /* ⅓ VULGAR FRACTION ONE THIRD */
#define XK_twothirds   0x0ab1  /* ⅔ VULGAR FRACTION TWO THIRDS */
#define XK_onefifth    0x0ab2  /* ⅕ VULGAR FRACTION ONE FIFTH */
```

I tried:

```bsh
$ sed -e 's/U+\([0-9A-Fa-f]\{4\}\)/\u\1/' < /usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h
```

That just "ignores" the `\u`. So, boiling it down to some [`sed`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sed) testcases with the Pilcrow "¶":

```bsh
$ echo 00B6 | sed -re $'s/(....)/echo "\u00B6"/e'
¶       # Good, display works, lets get the capture group:
$ echo 00B6 | sed -re $'s/(....)/echo "\u00B6 \\1"/e'
¶ 00B6  # So far, so good, lets prefix \u again:
$ echo 00B6 | sed -re $'s/(....)/echo "\u00B6 \u\\1"/e'
¶ 00B6  # Huh? Ok, trying double-wrapping
$ echo 00B6 | sed -re $'s/(....)/echo "\u00B6 \\u\\1"/e'
¶ 00B6  # Hey, where did the '\\u' go? Ok, try something else:
$ echo 00B6 | sed -re $'s/(....)/echo $(echo "\u00B6 \u\\1")/e'
¶ 00B6  # I give up
```

(Note: I also just now tried some variations of the above with `printf`. No change)

What am I missing? Why can't I use the evaluate flag of [`sed`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sed) like that?

Edit: I am aware, that this can be worked around with `while read echo eval` and be solved with other languages/tools, and appreciated(+1d) the answers.

For this question however I'd be most interested in a solution with [`sed`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sed) or know why the above commands produce this output and/or why it is not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With perl:

```bsh
perl -CS -pe 's/\bU\+([\dA-Fa-f]{4})\b/chr(hex($1))/eg' /usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h
```

This tells perl to look for `U+0000`, convert the `0000` to hex, and then replace it with the character represented by that number.

If you want to replace the contents of the file you can do:

```bsh
perl -i -CD -pe 's/\bU\+([\dA-Fa-f]{4})\b/chr(hex($1))/eg' /path/to/file
```

Comment: why use `-CS` ? whatis mean?

Comment: @Babyy http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html . It means use unicode mode. keeps perl from complaining about "wide characters".

Comment: @AlexStragies not sure. I tend to only use sed for really simple stuff. Perl's capabilities are way more powerful (plus basic/extended regex is a PITA).

Comment: Your solution is not quite complete. You missed the hex digits. `\d` needs to be replaced by `(\d|[A-F])`. I didn't spot it at first, cause I focused on the replacement part, and the flags.

Comment: We all missed the Braille patterns much further down the file, which use small hex letters, so the RegEx needs another addition: "a-f"

Answer (score 3):

Pass the (modified) sed output line-wise through `echo -e ""`:

```bsh
sed -e 's/U+\([0-9A-Fa-f]\{4\}\)/\\u\1/' </usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h |
while read -r line;do echo -e "$line";done
```

Comment: I also thought of this workaround, +1. Much lower performance, but not significant for a dataset of this size. So, you also have not found a more direct way?

Comment: BTW: Your command is missing the `-e` after `echo`

Comment: Sorry, i'm using mksh. Always forgot the `-e` for bash users...